# L3 data cache ECC error

Tags: linux, ecc, cpu-cache, memory-error

I happened to have a terminal window open in Linux (Debian) and, as I was browsing the web, I heard a beep so I looked to see what happened and I found the following message in the terminal window:

```
Message from syslogd@orion at Jul 26 06:20:44 ...
 kernel:[47674.818576] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.

Message from syslogd@orion at Jul 26 06:20:44 ...
 kernel:[47674.818620] [Hardware Error]: CPU:0 (15:2:0) MC4_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|AddrV|-|-|CECC]: 0x9d6c4094011c011b

Message from syslogd@orion at Jul 26 06:20:44 ...
 kernel:[47674.818626] [Hardware Error]: MC4 Error Address: 0x000000000144fb64

Message from syslogd@orion at Jul 26 06:20:44 ...
 kernel:[47674.818630] [Hardware Error]: MC4 Error (node 0): L3 data cache ECC error.

Message from syslogd@orion at Jul 26 06:20:44 ...
 kernel:[47674.818633] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, tx: GEN, mem-tx: RD
```

Is this bad? Should I worry about my CPU?

Comment: That could be caused by actual hardware error or a kernel bug. You should run at least 2 passes of Memtest scan to make sure.  If you don't get errors in Memtest, you have a buggy kernel and should upgrade/downgrade it.

Comment: Almost forgot. A buggy BIOS can also trigger that kind of error in the kernel.

Comment: It was the RAM. It's been 3 and a half years... I don't know why I didn't reply to you soonner. @Larssend please put your comment as answer so I can mark it as correct. Memtest showed that the RAM was defective. Thank you!